# Partial Page Curl, open new view full size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have curled the main screen to show a UITableView, when I click on a table cell I am opening a new view like so:

```
if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Filter Results"]){
        FilterViewController *dw = [[FilterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        dw.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:dw animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

However this opens the view in the curl rather than the whole page. Is there a way to open it and not stay within the curl?

Comment: you want to give page curl animation?

Comment: No, in FirstViewController I am presenting a new viewcontroller using the PartialCurl animation, when I try to open a new viewcontroller from within the PartialCurl it shows it inside of the partial curl rather than as a full window